# Equal Legendre symbols.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Any hints for proving that if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes such that $p=4a+q$ for some integer $a$ then $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{q}\right)$? I have tried using quadratic reciprocity but I don't seem to get to any answer, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that $p\equiv q \text{ } ( \text{ mod } 4) $ but I don't know how to use this fact. I can use any result given on a first number theory course. So far i have this:
Since $p$ is congruent to $4a$ modulo $q$ then $\left( \frac{p}{q}\right) = \left( \frac{4a}{q}\right) = \left( \frac{4}{q}\right) \left(\frac{a}{q}\right)$. Similarly $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-4a}{p}\right) = \left( \frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$. Then $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{4}{q}\right)\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$. Thus, by quadratic reciprocity, $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}} = \left(\frac{4}{q}\right)\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$, but $\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}=2a+\left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)^2$, so $\left(\frac{4}{q}\right)\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)^2}$.

Comment: Well, you ought to know how to evaluate $\left( \frac 4{\psi}\right)$ for any prime $\psi$.

Comment: That's 1 for any prime, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you have already shown that
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)$$
Further,
$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$$
Since
$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}
-\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) &\text{if }p\equiv q\equiv 3\mod 4\\
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) & \text{if } p\equiv 1\mod 4\text{ or }q\equiv 1\mod 4
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}
+1 & \text{if }p\equiv 1\mod 4\\
-1 & \text{if }q\equiv 3\mod 4
\end{cases}$$
The answer follows from the fact that $p\equiv q\mod 4$

Comment: Since $\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)^2=1$ as $p$ is a odd prime